# Need to display only array value in JSON output

Tags: php, json

How to display only array value in JSON out in php

I am using below PHP code

```
echo '{"aaData":'.json_encode($user_details).'}';
```

And it return below output

```
{"aaData": [
    {"id":"31","name":"Elankeeran","email":"ekeeran@yahoo.com","activated":"0","phone":""}
]}
```

But I need JSON output like below

```
{"aaData": [
    {"31","Elankeeran","ekeeran@yahoo.com","0","1234"}
]}
```

Any one please help on this.

Comment: Your example is not valid JSON. `{}` refers to an object, and objects must have properties like `{"id":"31"}`. The output returned by your PHP code is valid JSON.

Comment: Why do you create parts of your JSON manually?!

Comment: I am using jquery DataTable they asking in this format

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$rows = array();
foreach ($user_details as $row) {
  $rows[] = array_values((array)$row);
}

echo json_encode(array('aaData'=> $rows));
```

which outputs:

```
{"aaData": [
    ["31","Elankeeran","test@yahoo.com","0","1234"],
    ["33","Elan","test@gmail.com","1",""]
]}
```

Comment: Dor Shemer still I am getting same result

Comment: @Elankeeran What's the output of `var_dump($user_details)` ?

Comment: var_dump out here

array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#20 (5) { ["id"]=> string(2) "31" ["name"]=> string(10) "Elankeeran" ["email"]=> string(17) "ekeeran@yahoo.com" ["activated"]=> string(1) "0" ["phone"]=> string(0) "" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#21 (5) { ["id"]=> string(2) "33" ["name"]=> string(4) "Elan" ["email"]=> string(21) "keeran.test@gmail.com" ["activated"]=> string(1) "1" ["phone"]=> string(0) "" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#22 (5) { ["id"]=> string(2) "34" ["name"]=> string(6) "Elango" ["email"]=> string(17) "elango@elango.com" ["activated"]=> string(1) "0" ["phone"]=> string(0) "" } }

Comment: In that case, you should probaby do

`json_encode(array('aaData'=> array_values((array)($user_details[0]))))`

Comment: thanks now i am getting one row like below
{"aaData":["31","Elankeeran","ekeeran@yahoo.com","0",""]} 
how to get all rows

Comment: @Elankeeran You should've been more clear in your original question. I revised my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6922/discussion-between-elankeeran-and-dor-shemer)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '{"aaData":'.json_encode(array_values($user_details)).'}';
```

should do it

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP is already producing valid JSON. To access items in it from JavaScript, use patterns like:

```
obj.aaData[0].name;
// Elankeeran

obj.aaData[0].email;
// email@yahoo.com
```