# How to format JSON output to display only values in quotes and not keys?

Tags: php, ajax, json, cordova, jquery-mobile

This is related to [Need to display only array value in JSON output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953536/need-to-display-only-array-value-in-json-output) asked earlier.

I just want to show only values like

```
[
"autoComplete",
"ColdFusion",
"jQuery Mobile"
];
```

Background:
I am using and AJAX call via Jquery mobile to retrieve data from server (language:PHP). I want to use https://github.com/commadelimited/autoComplete.js in my Phonegap Application.

Please advice! I am new to JSON.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.  What have you tried? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: `echo json_encode(array('autoComplete', 'ColdFusion', 'jquery Mobile'))` does exactly what you want.

Comment: The values are generated dynamically from the database so could not do json_encode(array('autoComplete', 'ColdFusion', 'jquery Mobile')) Just posted my answer which is working (After working on it for hours!!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jonathan.

However I found the solution as below. I hope that it is useful to someone else too.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());
$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $records[] = $row["title"];
}


mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode($records);
```

Answer (score 1):

when using json_encode, any array that has a zero based numeric index (meaning it is not an associative array and starts with 0 and is not missing any numbers) will be converted to a javascript array instead of a js object literal. You can use array_values in php to get all the values from an array numerically indexed.

```
<?php
//a generic array
$a = array(
    'foo'=>'bar',
    'one'=>'two',
    'three'=>'four');

//display the array in php
var_dump($a);
echo '<br>';

//json encode it
$json = json_encode($a);
var_dump($json);
echo '<br>';

//json encode just the values
$json = json_encode(array_values($a));
var_dump($json);
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/hv06zn